# Displaying a jtable starting from column 100 - java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

If I have a jTable ( inside a jScrollPane ) with 1000+ columns. Is it possible when creating this jtable that the first column to be displayed is the 100th column ? all the previous columns could be seen by scrolling backwards. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
int columnToScrollTo = 100;
table.scrollRectToVisible(table.getCellRect(0, columnToScrollTo, true));
```